# Determine the order of the rate of convergence for these values

Tags: numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

> Consider the recurrence relation $x_n=2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ and the general solution $z_n=\alpha(1+\sqrt{3})^n+\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n$.
>
> For which values of $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ does the general solution converge? Determine the order of the rate of convergence for these values.

I've found $z_n$ to be convergent for $\alpha=0$ and $\beta\in (-\infty,\infty)$.
But how do I go about determining the the order of the rate of convergence?

Answer (score 0):

When there is convergence,

$$z_n=\beta(1-\sqrt3)^n$$ is simply a geometric progression of common ratio $1-\sqrt3$ and the convergence is linear.

Comment: Thank you. Would the following be a correct answer?
When there is convergence:
$$z_n=\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n.$$  
We see that
$$c=\frac{|z_{n+1}|}{|z_n|}=\frac{|\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^{n+1}|}{|\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n|}\to\sqrt{3}-1\quad\text{ for }n\to\infty.$$  
Since $c<1$, the rate of convergence is linear.

Comment: @user405381 You forgot the absolute value.

Comment: Where did I forget it?

Comment: @user405381: oops, no, sorry.